# How to initialize Class<? extends MyClass>

Tags: java, class

I have an abstract method

```
public abstract Class<? extends MyClass> getMySpecialClass();
```

In another method I'd like to have an instant of this class. How would I do this?

```
public void method(){
   Class<? extends MyClass> mySpecialClass = getMySpecialClass();
   MyClass myClass = new ???
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about calling `newInstance`?

```
MyClass myClass = mySpecialClass.newInstance();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

The class must have a nullary constructer (one with no parameters).

Comment: Ah thanks, couldn't find that. No idea how to search for that ;)